# Subversion Force Refresh

Tags: svn

Does such a thing exist in subversion?

In perforce we used to have to do this quite often especially when Perforce got the incremental update wrong - It does not seem possible in Subversion

Is an alternative to delete the .svn file and do an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn up` generally does the trick. Occasionally, your working copy can get into a bad state, requiring `svn cleanup`. Very occasionally, even that doesn't work, and the simplest fix is to `svn co` into a clean directory.

For a prohibitively large working copy, you might be able to avoid `svn co` if you can isolate a subtree causing problems, delete it, then `svn up`.

Answer (score 0):

The open source [SVN Monitor](http://www.svnmonitor.com/default.shtml) program allows you to specify your repositories and your local working copies that correspond to those repositories, and then to schedule automated updates of your working copies.

So, whenever someone makes a commit to a repository, your working copy will automatically get an `svn up` applied to it.